# Módulos do Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Estou tentando fazer um scrap no site de uma faculdade, costumo fazer em JavaScript com o CasperJS e até aí tudo ok. Porém agora estamos tentando usar Python pra isso e estou tendo problemas com esse erro:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py:13: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import fnmatch, glob, traceback, errno, sys, atexit, locale, imp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unicsul-ead.py", line 38, in <module>
    polos=polos+r['https://www.cruzeirodosulvirtual.com.br/webservice/nossos-polos.php?polos='+str(p)]['polos']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Eu estou utlizando esses imports:

```
from me.robot import Execution
import multi_req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from money_parser import price_str
import sys
import glob
# import pp
# import json
```

Como sou bastante leigo com isso, eu notei que ele dá um `TypeError` mas mesmo assim retorna algo sobre algum `import`, porém não entendo bem. Alguém saberia me dizer sobre? Estou pesquisando e não entendi quase nada.

Bom, este é o código completo:

```
from me.robot import Execution
import multi_req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from money_parser import price_str
import sys
import glob
# import pp
# import json

if len(sys.argv)<2:
    raise Exception('Passar o nome do arquivo é necessário!')


if(len(sys.argv)==4):
    exe=Execution(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[3]))
else:
    exe=Execution(sys.argv[1])

exe.start()

keepgoing_local=True
keepgoing_course=True

if(len(sys.argv) > 2 and sys.argv[2]!='-'): #tem keepgoing
    l=sys.argv[2].split(';')
    keepgoing_course_name=l[3]
    keepgoing_uf_name=l[7]
    keepgoing_city_name=l[9]
    keepgoing_local_name=l[11]

    keepgoing_local=False
    keepgoing_course=False

polos_urls,polos=[],[]

for p in range(1, 1000, 100):
    r=multi_req.scrap(['https://www.cruzeirodosulvirtual.com.br/webservice/nossos-polos.php?polos='+str(p)], resp_type='json')
    polos=polos+r['https://www.cruzeirodosulvirtual.com.br/webservice/nossos-polos.php?polos='+str(p)]['polos']

for p in polos:

    # print(keepgoing_uf_name.encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower()+b' == '+p['uf'].encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower())
    # print(keepgoing_city_name.encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower()+b' == '+p['cidade'].encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower())
    # print(keepgoing_local_name.encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower()+b' == '+p['nome'].encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower())

    if(not keepgoing_local and keepgoing_uf_name.encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower()==p['uf'].encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower() and keepgoing_city_name.encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower()==p['cidade'].encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower() and keepgoing_local_name.encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower()==p['nome'].encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower()):
        keepgoing_local=True
        exe.log('keepgoing polo: '+p['nome'].lower())

    if(keepgoing_local):
        if(p['classes'].find(' graduacao ')>-1):
            rp=multi_req.scrap(['https://www.cruzeirodosulvirtual.com.br'+p['polo']])
            psoup=BeautifulSoup(rp[next(iter(rp))], 'html.parser')

            curls=[]
            for c in psoup.select(".cursos .titulo-curso-sl"):
                curls.append(c.parent.a['href'])
                if(len(curls) % 10 == 0):
                    course_scrap=multi_req.scrap(curls)

                    for rc in course_scrap.keys():
                        csoup=BeautifulSoup(course_scrap[rc], 'html.parser')

                        if(not keepgoing_course and keepgoing_course_name.encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower()==csoup.h1.text.strip().encode('UTF-8', 'surrogateescape').strip().lower()):
                            keepgoing_course=True
                            exe.log('keepgoing course: '+keepgoing_course_name.lower())
                            continue

                        if(keepgoing_course):
                            if(len(csoup.find_all(id="investimento-hide"))):
                                exe.add_price(
                                    ies_sigle='UNICSUL EAD',
                                    course_name=csoup.h1.text.strip(),
                                    price=price_str(csoup.find_all(id="investimento-hide")[0].h3.text),
                                    state_name=p['uf'],
                                    city_name=p['cidade'],
                                    local_name=p['nome'],
                                    modality='EAD'
                                )

                    curls=[]

exe.end()
```

Comment: O problema não está no import - ele só dá um aviso de "deprecated" - o erro é que a variável "r" que você tenta usar com uma sintaxe de dicionário contém `None`  - mas como você não colou o código todo é impossível orientar a correção.

Comment: Vou editar e colocar o código, to na correria e esqueci. Só um minutinho!

Comment: Eu recomendo que você use o Scrapy: https://scrapy.org.

Answer (score -1):

Sobre o problema "DeprecationWarning:" tente instalar a biblioteca cloudpickle.

pip install cloudpickle
ou
pip3 install cloudpickle